# Make an SQL query return duplicate rows without using the UNION ALL close

Tags: java, sql, db2, db2-luw

I have a use case that imply returning all the records even if the same id is specified many times

```
select d.id from data d where d.id in (1420552,  1420553)
union all
select d.id from data d where d.id in (1420552, 1420553)
```

As the "IN" predicate is just translated as an "OR" between all the specified values it will not give me the desired result.

```
select d.id from data d where d.id in (1420552,  1420553, 1420552, 1420553)
```

Therefore i'm wondering if there is any alternative to get the desired result.
Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Very weird use case...

But assuming your platform and version of Db2 supports table value constructor...

Try

```
with cte(id) 
  as (values (1420552),(1420553)
            ,(1420552),(1420553) )
select d.id
  from data d
       join cte c on d.id = c.id;
```

Comment: Hi Charles, thank you so much for your answer. Your suggested query is returning exactly the desired result. As this query use Common Table Expression (cte) this SQL feature is not supported by the hibernate V3.x. The project use HQL for portability reasons, i'll talk to the head developer next Monday to ask him if i can introduce a native query in the application for this special use case.

Comment: @user3072470 You can do it as a nte, I just prefer cte.  Don't forget to upvote and mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use a `cross join`:

```
select d.id
from data d cross join
     (select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1 union all
      select 2 from sysibm.sysdummy1 union all
     ) n
where d.id in (1420552,1420553);
```

Or more concisely as:

```
select d.id
from data d cross join
     (values (1), (2)) v(n)
where d.id in (1420552,1420553);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. As i mention it in my question the same Id can be used many times in the query, for example if 1420552 is used in the "IN" predicate 5 times the query must return 5 times the same row with the id = 1420552, i hope that i managed explaining the requirements. `select d.id
from data d cross join
     (values (1), (2)) v(n)
where d.id in (1420552,1420552,1420552,1420552,1420552,1420553,1420553,1420553);`